# ERROR Exiting Kafka due to fatal exception (kafka.Kafka$) on Windows - Apache Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm getting below error while starting the Kafka-Server on Windows machine. I've downloaded Scala 2.11 - `kafka_2.11-2.1.0.tgz` from the link: https://kafka.apache.org/downloads and I did the following steps:

1. Go to `config` folder in `Apache Kafka` (`C:\Apache-Kafka\kafka_2.11-2.1.0\config`) and edit `“server.properties”` using any text editor.
2. Find `log.dirs` and repelace after `“=/tmp/kafka-logs”` to `C:\Apache-Kafka\kafka_2.11-2.1.0\kafka-logs`.

Now simply start the server:

```
>kafka-server-start.bat C:\Apache-Kafka\kafka_2.11-2.1.0\config
```

Error:

```
C:\Apache-Kafka\kafka_2.11-2.1.0\bin\windows>kafka-server-start.bat C:\Apache-Kafka\kafka_2.11-2.1.0\config
[2018-12-14 21:09:34,566] INFO Registered kafka:type=kafka.Log4jController MBean (kafka.utils.Log4jControllerRegistration$)
[2018-12-14 21:09:34,583] ERROR Exiting Kafka due to fatal exception (kafka.Kafka$)
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: C:\Apache-Kafka\kafka_2.11-2.1.0\config
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:83)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:102)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:230)
        at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:361)
        at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:407)
        at java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newInputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:384)
        at java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream(Files.java:152)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.loadProps(Utils.java:560)
        at kafka.Kafka$.getPropsFromArgs(Kafka.scala:42)
        at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:58)
        at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)

C:\Apache-Kafka\kafka_2.11-2.1.0\bin\windows>
```

Note: I've already setup Apache Zookeeper on my Windows machine and it's running on port `2181`.

I run the command using run as administrator.

Comment: I am able to solve this issue, Just fire this query from Apache Kafka root folder

Comment: `.\bin\windows\zookeeper-server-start.bat .\config\zookeeper.properties`

Comment: If you are using kafka image of bitnami then run command

    kafka-server-start.sh ../config/server.properties

Answer (score 1):

Try this after kafka-server-start.bat

use this: ....\config\server.properties with slash between 2 dots

in my case was [image: "C:\kafka_2.12-2.5.0\kafka_2.12-2.5.0\bin\windows>kafka-server-start.bat ....\config\server.properties"]

Comment: It is simply returning nothing just next line comes in cmd console and zookeeper doesnt even start. How to resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

In general we must not use C: drive to store kafka-logs. You can try using the drive other than the C: for storing Kafka logs. It must work.

Change the property log.dirs={Drive other than C:}/tmp/kafka-logs present in KafkaHome/config/server.properties.

Comment: While using a separate disk is preffered, for development, most people don't usually have more than one drives

Answer (score 0):

this cmd works for me

```
C:\kafka\bin\windows>kafka-server-start.bat ../../config/server.properties
```

or try this (I guess you set your environment variable)

```
C:\kafka>kafka-server-start.bat  config/server.properties
```